# WPF TabControl with ContentControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol

I have searched a lot on SO and didn't find answer to my problems.
I want to use TabControl with MVVM. Here is how I add TabControl to MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:PartnersViewModel}">
            <views:PartnersView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:ProjectsViewModel}">
            <views:ProjectsView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Window.DataContext>
        <models:ApplicationViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding PageViewModels}"  TabStripPlacement="Left">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
```

PageViewModels is `ObservableCollection<IPageViewModel>`.
`IPageViewModel` is simple interface with one property `Name`. There are 2 implementation of this interface `PartnersViewModel` and `ProjectsViewModel`.

```
public class ProjectsViewModel : IPageViewModel
{
    public String Name
    {
        get { return "Projects"; }
    }
}

public class PartnersViewModel : IPageViewModel
{
    public String Name
    {
        get { return "Partners"; }
    }
}
```

I want each tab to be displayed as ContentControl. Header text is taken from Name property. My ProjectsView and PartnersView looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WANIRPartners.Views.ProjectsView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" >
  <Grid>
    <Label Content="Projects Content" />
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Using this code, header and content in `TabControl` is exactly the same. 'Projects Content'/'Partners Content' are shown in tab headers and also(this is ok) in tab content. When I change `<Label/>` to `<DataGrid/>` tab headers contains datagrid (sic!). 
How can I get this working properly. I mean how can I display headers as value of property `Name` and tab content as properly rendered `<views:PartnersView />` or `<views:ProjectsView />` depending on what is in `PageViewModels`.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that it's picking correct `DataTemplate` by `DataType` but then it's ignoring `ItemTemplate` for header? Does `TabControl` have default template?

Comment: It seems you are right. DataTemplate is correctly chosen but ItemTemplate is ignored. What do you mean by default template for TabControl? Sorry, I'm just starting with WPF.

Comment: What I mean is that XAML you shown should work, and does work on my end. I see nothing obvious wrong with it so my question is do you change template of `TabControl` (how it looks), do you use something like MahApps or it's default look. Explicit `ItemTempate` should take priority over implicit `DataType` template

Comment: I'm using Elysium, and after remove elysium everything work fine. Thanks very much. How can I get this working using Elysium?

Answer (score 1):

your code should work, dont have a IDE atm. you can also use Snoop to check your bindings at runtime. i changed the ContentTemplate to:

```
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding .}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
```

and it works. but even your code works in my testapp.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered solution for Elysium. Adding fter adding code belowe everything work fine.

```
 <TabControl.Resources>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}">
         <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
     </Style>
 </TabControl.Resources>
```