# How do I initialize viewmodel's datacontext when the application starts?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I started to use MVVMLight framework recently.

When I use ContentPresenter to swtich between ViewModel, it seems like it initialize the datacontext when it first displays.

However, I want it to initialize it's datacontext so it can keep track of any change from the initial loading of the application, or at least share the data with other viewmodel(I assume maybe I can use dataservice to keep track of all the data, but I could not find a right example to use it with contentpresenter & MVVMLight).

Below is the sample code I made. When I click Review button, "usercontrolview" will display "Picture Saved", however "contentpresenterview" will display "No Picture".

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrLXj.png)

MainView.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="CaptureButton" Content="Capture" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="34,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"
            Command="{Binding CaptureCommand}"/>
    <Button x:Name="ReviewButton" Content="Review" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="146,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"
            Command="{Binding ShowReviewCommand}"/>
    <TextBlock FontSize="36"
               FontWeight="Bold"
               Foreground="Purple"
               Text="{Binding CaptureStatus}"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               TextWrapping="Wrap" />

    <Grid x:Name="usercontrolview" Visibility="{Binding ReviewModeOn, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Margin="0,50,150,0">
        <view:ReviewView/>
    </Grid>
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentpresenterview" Content="{Binding CurrentContent}" Margin="150,50,0,0"/>
</Grid>
```

MainViewModel.cs (Partial)

```
public MainViewModel()
    {
        CaptureStatus = "No Picture";

        CaptureCommand = new RelayCommand(Capture);
        ShowReviewCommand = new RelayCommand(ShowReview);

        ReviewModeOn = false;
    }


    public RelayCommand CaptureCommand { get; private set; }
    private void Capture()
    {
        CaptureStatus = "Pictures Saved";
        Messenger.Default.Send<NotificationMessage>(new NotificationMessage("Pictures Saved"), "Captured");
    }
    public RelayCommand ShowReviewCommand { get; private set; }
    private void ShowReview()
    {
        ReviewModeOn = !ReviewModeOn;
        CurrentContent = ContentViewModel;
    }
```

And my template for ReviewViewModel & ReviewContentPresenterViewModel

```
    public ***ViewModel()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage>(this, "Captured", Captured);

        CaptureStatus = "No Picture";
    }

    private void Captured(NotificationMessage notificationMessage)
    {
        CaptureStatus = notificationMessage.Notification;
    }

    private string _captureStatus;
    public string CaptureStatus
    {
        get { return _captureStatus; }
        set { Set(ref _captureStatus, value); }
    }
```

======================= Update =======================

My template for ReviewView & ReviewContentPresenterView.
It takes DataContext by locator.

```
<UserControl x:Class="***View"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ignore="http://www.galasoft.ch/ignore"
    mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
    DataContext="{Binding ***ViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

    <Grid Background="Gray">
        <TextBlock FontSize="36"
               FontWeight="Bold"
               Foreground="Purple"
               Text="{Binding CaptureStatus}"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your DataContext in the root Grid and all it's children is the MainViewModel and you want other DataContext for ContentPresenter. Create the other ViewModel as a resource e.g.

```
<Grid>
<Grid.Resources>
    <local:TheViewModelIWant x:Key=ContentViewModel/>      
</Grid.Resources>
...
...
<ContentPresenter DataContext={StaticResource ContentViewModel} ...
```

(By the way, if you are already creating an instance of TheViewModelIWant somewhere e.g. in other ViewModels or view code behind then you can stop using that instance and access this instance in C# code as `Resources["ContentViewModel"]`)

Comment: Thanks Greg, I have a question about your way though. I am using MVVMlight model, so each View has it's own ViewModel as their DataContext. If I use above code, won't it overwrite current view model? or is it possible to use both DataContext? And Could you clarify little more about your last comment? I'm still learning C#.

Comment: Hi, for example, if the root (the top-level element) in the XAML is a Grid and you set the Grid's DataContext (or even the View's e.g. Window's DataContext) to be the normal view model that's fine. Then if you have a child control in the Window or Grid you can get its DataContext and it only affects itself and its own child controls - it's parents/peers and their child controls are not affected at all.

Comment: ("VM" - ViewModel)  You also make a good point. You can have a separate class (object) exposed as a property in your normal VM that you can bind your content to - e.g. perhaps consider an approach that doesn't use a separate VM. I have used separate DataContexts on occasion before but only in cases where I wanted to separate purely View aspects from Model aspects - not to have distinct VMs. Views generally map to a single VM so if you seek multiple VMs for same view it's a clue to look at your approach. Classes can be shared across VMs but they don't need to be VMs themselves.

Comment: Then your approach might not work on mine. Because I need different VM for different view that is chosen by ContentPresenter. For this example, I only had one View/ViewModel for it's Concent, but most of times I use multiple of View/ViewModel similar to a tab mode. So injecting one DataContext will not work, and I rather call it from View itself.

Comment: You don't want to switch views using content that way - although it's understandable why you my think of that approach and I give you credit. What you really want is just to have separate Views each with their own ViewModel as you say. Just put them all in one grid but only make one visible at a time. Bind the Visibility property of each view to the same property in the MainViewModel and use some kind of converter with a ConverterParameter e.g. name/index unique to each view such that the convert only returns Visibility Visible when the "SelectedView" property in ViewModel matches the param.

Comment: When I started, I think I used something like this as a model: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29727860/wpf-tabcontrol-with-contentcontrol (Not exactly sure which one, it's been awhile) Anyway, I will change to your suggestion. But before I do that, could you explain why that's bad approach and when should I use such way? Just for a future reference :)

Comment: Hi, it's the concept of (custom) Controls vs application-level. ContentPresenter is a model for Controls to display their content. You don't need this model because the Contr

Comment: ...Control model works by XAML automatically setting the Content property (usually named "Content") of your custom control just by virtue of the fact that you placed elements in the control in XAML. A <Button><TextBlock/></Button> for example. You're already inside a <Grid> which is a Panel for displaying chlld elements... so if you want to dynamically change views just wrap it in another grid as a placeholder and change the visibility property. This keeps the "pure-view" logic out of viewmodel where it doesn't add value to the model unless e.g. you're going to persist the view state.

Comment: To do it your way, you need a separate collection in the viewmodel for the view instances and then in the viewmodel, set currentcontent to the selected one. Your approach is not way-off, but it's a lot of pure "view" stuff in the "viewmodel". XAML isolates the two (generally) so your grid automatically acts as your ViewCollection class - then just make sure all views have Visibility "Collapsed" except the one you want to show. Since you have other controls in your root grid, just add another grid to wrap all your views - this grid replaces your contentpresenter. Best.

Comment: Since you expressed interest in deeper understanding, I'll share with you, as a philosophical note, that there are some variance in perspective/practice of the viewmodel. To me, the kind of issue/discernment that you are faced with is actually a shortcoming of WPF. I think viewmodel architecture should be all about mapping your (typically persistent, e.g. DB) data (model) to the view. With WPF, your one ViewModel is pretty much your only easy binding source for both model and (sadly) _view_ data.  The DataContext is too "broad and brutish". Should be an aux DC for pure view logic/data.

Comment: WPF's own name gives it away. The P stands for "Presentation", The idea is to present data flexibly and in different views. However often people end up (for the aforementioned convenience) mixing too much view stuff with the viewmodel. You don't need "Presentation" for the view - the view _is_ the Presentation : -)  (No framework is perfect and WPF is pretty powerful - I like it in general - although we all know the headache side of it : - ) )

Comment: In the XAML, you can add each View's ViewModel in the container Grid's Resources and for each view inside the container Grid, you can set the it's DataContext as initially mentioned, so each View will use its own ViewModel.

Comment: There's also the Frame-Page-Navigation model but for basic view switching that's more complex then it's worth IMHO - See: http://paulstovell.com/blog/wpf-navigation  For example you have to manage view (Page) instances and lifetimes and view state issues. It's seems more related to RESTful than desktop app. With all views in the grid and just set visibility - you're done.

Comment: Hi Greg, I have one more question. As I going back to my code to apply, I realized I used ContentControl, not ContentPresenter for my real application. I just want to make sure these two face similar problem, but just wanted to make sure. Is it?

Comment: Hi, I think the key is to look at the various WPF built-in elements and controls in terms of what their purpose is (in general). The purpose of a ContentControl is to provide specific functionality either _for_ it's content, as a Window, ScrollViewer or a Frame does, or it _allows_ content like a Button does. Again consider app-level vs. Custom Control. In fact, the Frame as mentioned is a custom ContentControl whose purpose is to navigate content (similar) to what you want to do _but_ as mentioned it has more of a URL/web/RESTful flavor to it and adds complexity...

Comment: ...part of the complexity is that the ContentControl (or ContentPresenter) only allows one child element so you have to have a separate collection that holds all your views and you have to switch the content as you are pursuing in initial post. You could pursue that, but really the purpose of ContentControl is for custom control development so it just boils down to the simplest most practical approach. To solve your problem, the Grid allows multiple children and so serves as your view collection as well as your view switcher (via view Visibility) is your simplest and most practical option...

Comment: ...and you don't have so much of the debug issues you are experiencing. Controls, including ContenControls are all about Templating capabilities. If you wanted to stay with a Control then the way to go is use one that allows multiple children like TabControl which is an ItemsControl (as is a ListBox). However, you don't need the overhead of a Control - you're not Templating anything, you just need a lightweight container - the Grid. If you look at the controls surrounding your original ContentPresenter you could look at using those in a TabControl (ItemsControl) DataTemplate (ItemTemplate)...

Comment: ...but for the immediate problem you presented in your OP adding all your views to the Grid is your solution. (If you are in no rush and you want Templating capabilities for your item (view) container and/or your items (views), then take your time and implement a custom ItemsControl/TabControl or use a TabControl with a Template - but I don't see that you need that from your OP).

Comment: By the way, to answer your other question - think about it - If a ContentControl is a Control that allows you to customize it's appearance using a Template (as all Controls do) _and_ somewhere in the visuals that make up the Template, the Content is supposed to be in there too, then how do you know where? Well, it's where the ContentPresenter is placed among the visual (elements) in the Template. In a Button Template (remember Button is a ContentControl), the ContentPresenter is generally placed in the center e.g. inside a border etc. such that the Content e.g. text is placed in the center.

Comment: Think of different house frame designs all with only one door frame. One house design (Template) has the door frame at the left, the other in the middle, and the other on the right. For each house you can put any door you want (Content) but it appears where it is based on what's around it. Well, that's all the ContentPresenter is, it's the door frame for where the door will show up relative to the rest of the house. Since you only have one house, you don't need a template nor the overhead of a ContentControl so the Grid is all you need.

Comment: Nice, that fixed most of my problem. I really wondered what I was doing wrong. It might be simple(?) mistake for few, but gave me a hard time. lol. I learned a lot from this post and your responses. Thanks Greg!

Comment: Yes, even the pre-packaged controls like Button, ListBox, ContentControl... are somewhat like samples. They should really point us to the power of the underlying Framework - the automatic Visual Tree layout and dependency and binding systems. Templating itself is built on top of that. One could even write their own templating system using Markup extensions. The point of this is not to take on such when new, but rather to not be so wowed by the higher level pre-packaged controls and feel free to be creative with the underlying systems that are the real power of WPF. Glad I could be helpful. :-)